# ChartJS, Multiple line in bar chart label

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js, bar-chart

I am using **ChartJS library** to draw chart in a PHP project. In a bar chart I want **the label in X-axis in two line**.

What is the way?

**My Current chart is like**

[image]

**I want my Chart like below**

[image]

Here is my Code Snippet

```
<?php   
 $array_data = sql::rows("attendance_summary_report","DateVal between 
 '{$previous_date}' and '{$last_date}' order by DateVal asc");
    //print_r($array_data);
    $level_array=array();
    $pre_array=array();
    $abs_array=array();
    if(is_array($array_data) && count($array_data)>0){
        foreach($array_data as $ad){
            if($ad['DayVal']==''){
                $ad['DayVal']='No Day';
                $ad['present']=0;
                $ad['absent']=0;
            }
            array_push($level_array, 
  $ad['DayVal']."\n".date('d/m',strtotime($ad['DateVal'])));
            array_push($pre_array,$ad['present']);
            array_push($abs_array,$ad['absent']);
        }
    }
 ?>
```

```js
<script>
  $(function () {
      var areaChartData = {
      labels  : <?php echo json_encode($level_array,true)?>,
      datasets: [......]
    }
    

    var barChartCanvas = $('#barChart').get(0).getContext('2d')
    var barChartData = jQuery.extend(true, {}, areaChartData)
    var temp0 = areaChartData.datasets[0]
    var temp1 = areaChartData.datasets[1]
    barChartData.datasets[0] = temp1
    barChartData.datasets[1] = temp0

    var barChart = new Chart(barChartCanvas, {
      type: 'bar', 
      data: barChartData,
      options: barChartOptions
    })
}
 </script>
```

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: @Adam some code added.

Comment: thanks, but it would be more helpful if you could provide a minimal standalone example. Please provide only html and js, there is no need to provide the backend php. It also seems that `barChartOptions` is not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by passing the label as an array of strings where each element represents a line, e.g.:

```
let labels = [
  'A', // normal label.
  ['First line', 'Second line', '...'] // multi-line label.
];
```

A working example:

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['A', ['Water', 'Heating'], 'C'],
    datasets: [{
      data: [1, 1, 1]
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```

Comment: `data: [1, 1, 1]` would be better to express that there are 3 data for 3 labels.

Comment: @HeadhunterKev Indeed; a small error and not one that materially affects the result.

Comment: Sure, but because that's the important part of the answer with the array and the line break I thought a "correction" (even a small one) is better for OP's understanding. Nice answer for sure.

Comment: You are _technically_ correct, which is the best kind of correct. I've edited the answer :)